# Icons in snippet editor don't match link color

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

On sites with non-blue accent colors, the *icons* next to the "Tidy" and "Reset" links in the snippet editor stay blue and don't match the accent color. For example, on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/):

> [image]